# Do phasers actually discharge a stream of pulsed energy projectiles into the target?

Tags: star-trek, phaser

I was reading [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapons_in_Star_Trek) and wanted to know if the following quote is accurate, and if it can be observed:

> phasers actually discharge a stream of pulsed energy projectiles into the target

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to people when they are hit by a phaser beam?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12474/31394)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Star Trek TNG Writers' Technical Manual](http://engineering.thetafleet.net/Journals/TNG/Franchise%20-%20Star%20Trek%20TNG%20Writer%27s%20Technical%20Manual%20(fourth%20season).pdf) states that phasers:

> ...work by drawing off energy stored in a small dilithium crystal, converting that energy into a collimated beam, which exits the emitter.  We won't go into the exact nature of the energy beam; suffice it to say that the beam manages to excite water molecules like a microwave oven (at the low end of the scale), up to being able to negate the nuclear forces holding matter together (at the high end), and various steps in between.

Given that description, you could substitute "stream" for "beam," handwave away "pulsed," substitute "discharge" for "emit," assume "projectiles" are roughly equivalent to "particles" and assume that wave/particle duality makes "projectiles" an acceptable way to describe an energy beam.

It's not an exact match, but recognizable.